# SQL query returns different results based on field

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the example below if I query my view giving a specific `ident` then it properly comes back and says that the order is complete.

If I then ask for all orders that are not complete though, it's returning that `ident` that it clearly just saw WAS complete.  How is this possible/

```sql
# select complete from orders_plus where ident = 8410;
 complete 
----------
 t
(1 row)

# select ident,complete from orders_plus where complete = false;
 ident | complete 
-------+----------
  8402 | f
  8410 | f
  8414 | f
(3 rows)
```

Here's the definition of the view:

```
# \d+ orders_plus
                       View "public.orders_plus"
    Column    |       Type        | Modifiers | Storage  | Description
--------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 ident        | integer           |           | plain    |
 station_id   | integer           |           | plain    |
 created      | date              |           | plain    |
 due          | date              |           | plain    |
 month        | date              |           | plain    |
 comments     | character varying |           | extended |
 name         | character varying |           | extended |
 ud           | real              |           | plain    |
 dp           | real              |           | plain    |
 swrv         | real              |           | plain    |
 sh           | real              |           | plain    |
 jmsw         | real              |           | plain    |
 sw           | real              |           | plain    |
 prrv         | real              |           | plain    |
 mhsw         | real              |           | plain    |
 bmsw         | real              |           | plain    |
 mp           | real              |           | plain    |
 pr           | real              |           | plain    |
 st           | real              |           | plain    |
 rsw          | real              |           | plain    |
 rsh          | real              |           | plain    |
 rpr          | real              |           | plain    |
 rmp          | real              |           | plain    |
 total_points | real              |           | plain    |
 complete     | boolean           |           | plain    |
View definition:
 SELECT o.ident, o.station_id, o.created, o.due, o.month, o.comments, o.name,
    o.ud, o.dp, o.swrv, o.sh, o.jmsw, o.sw, o.prrv, o.mhsw, o.bmsw, o.mp, o.pr,
    o.st, o.rsw, o.rsh, o.rpr, o.rmp, o.total_points,
    COALESCE(sum(w.ud) >= o.ud AND sum(w.dp) >= o.dp AND sum(w.swrv) >= o.swrv AND sum(w.sh) >= o.sh AND sum(w.jmsw) >= o.jmsw AND sum(w.sw) >= o.sw AND sum(w.prrv) >= o.prrv AND sum(w.mhsw) >= o.mhsw AND sum(w.bmsw) >= o.bmsw AND sum(w.mp) >= o.mp AND sum(w.pr) >= o.pr AND sum(w.st) >= o.st AND sum(w.rsw) >= o.rsw AND sum(w.rsh) >= o.rsh AND sum(w.rpr) >= o.rpr AND sum(w.rmp) >= o.rmp, false) AS complete
   FROM orders o
   LEFT JOIN production_work w ON o.ident = w.order_id
  GROUP BY o.ident;
```

Comment: My first impression - a corrupted index. If the table has indexes on the columns, try `reindex orders_plus`.

Comment: what are indexes on `\d+ orders_plus`?..

Comment: It's a view, which doesn't seem to have indexes.  I updated the question to show the \d+ output

Answer (score -1):

ident is not the primary key. You have 2 records for the same ident (at least) one is t, one is f.

Comment: Again, this is a VIEW so there's no primary key.  the order table has ident as the primary key, and you can see from the first select I show there is only a single entry with that ident.